# SQL Access in excel, join excel not responding

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I use excel to query some sheets internally, when I do a join it ends up crashing my excel. For example the below query crashes my excel spreadsheets. ie getting not responding error.

```
select 
cdbl(afs.[ Value])
from [database$] as data 
left join [AFS$] as afs on data.[EUC_ID]=afs.[PositionID]
```

However if I use something like below, the query works.

```
select 
afs.[Value]
from [AFS$] as afs
```

does anyone know why? How can I fix this? I am using excel 2013.

here is my language settings:

[image]

Comment: `Replace(cdbl(afs.[Value]),",",".")` or vice-versa. Although you are in Canada, probably you are having the US language settings?

Comment: What Values do you have - when working?

Comment: @Vityata , the query seems to work, although i am getting the not responding error still. I also posted my language settings above. Yes I am in Canada.

Comment: @Gustav , they are always numbers.

Comment: Note the **space** before the word _Value_ in: `cdbl(afs.[ Value])`. Is it intentional?